# Silverlight and an online MySQL database

Tags: mysql, silverlight

Can I make a Silverlight application who get his data from an online MySQL database on a web hosting?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you'll need to throw a WCF interface on top of the MySQL database. Probably the easiest way to do this is with [WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/get-started-with-wcf-ria-services).

Comment: But thats with a local database... I want to connect to an online DB (database1.hosting2go.nl)

Comment: No, that is with any database.